# Remove prefix with special characters in Python Pandas Series

Tags: pandas, replace, series

How do I remove the `Bale + Damon -` prefix in the series below?

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.Series(['Bale + Damon - Le Mans 66', 'Bale + Damon - Ford', 'Bale + Damon - vs.', 'Bale + Damon - Ferrari'])
print(x)
0    Bale + Damon - Le Mans 66
1    Bale + Damon - Ford
2    Bale + Damon - vs.
3    Bale + Damon - Ferrari
```

Desired output:

```
print(x2)
0    Le Mans 66
1    Ford
2    vs.
3    Ferrari
```

I have tried `x2 = x.str.replace('Bale + Damon - ','')`, but it doesn't alter the original series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can also use [`Series.str.partition`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.partition.html)

```
x.str.partition(' - ').iloc[:,-1]
0    Le Mans 66
1          Ford
2           vs.
3       Ferrari
Name: 2, dtype: object
```

**UPDATE**

#### [`Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.partition.html) with `regex=False`

```
x = x.str.replace('Bale + Damon - ','',regex=False)

#0    Le Mans 66
#1          Ford
#2           vs.
#3       Ferrari
#dtype: object
```

Comment: See my comment on YO and BEN_W's answer. Still looks like a hack to me.

Comment: regex=False is what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

In your case

```
x.str.split(' - ',n=1).str[-1]   

0    Le Mans 66
1          Ford
2           vs.
3       Ferrari
dtype: object
```

Comment: it does handle this particular case but won't do with a more complicated series. Imagine I have many " - " occurrences. I do need a solution to replace exactly "Bale + Damon - " with "".